# How to calculate the amount of time, to the minute, until next Monday?

Tags: python, datetime

I have found this

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)
datetime.date(2009, 10, 26)
```

But this returns the number of days until next Monday - how do I calculate this to the minute? I.e., not all times on Tuesday will return the same amount of minutes until Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the datetime.datetime.now() method instead of datetime.date.today() you can use what you already have to get the time to next monday in minutes.

Comment: This works, but now I need to subtract the amount of hours in a day to bring the current datetime to midnight of the current day, before doing timedelta

Comment: @fertileneutrino: how so? If you want the minutes and seconds from right now, and not tonight at midnight, of course you don't need to subtract hours to get to midnight.

Comment: @Wooble - I was thinking out loud for a particular application for my webapp. I use midnight of next Monday as a field of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use datetime.datetime likes this:

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> today+datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 23, 0, 12, 2, 643512)
```

Is it this you are looking for??

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a timedelta between next monday and today and then print the minutes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = now = datetime.today()
today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)

print (timedelta(days=7-now.weekday()) + today - now).total_seconds()/60
```